# align two spans vertically with space in the middle in li

Tags: html, css

I have two spans in li (both texts) and would like to give some space in between and vertically align spans in li. how do I do that?
I am actually trying to populate it in javascript code

```
let subjectsUl = document.createElement("ul");
subjectsUl.classList.add("subject");
subjectList.forEach(
    (subject) =>
    {
        if (subject.subject !== "")
        {
            let liElt = document.createElement("li");
            liElt.innerHTML = "<span>" + subject.day + "</span>" + "<span>" + subject.subject + "</span>";
            subjectsUl.appendChild(liElt);
        }
    }
);
```

I would like to align days and subjects vertically and have some space in between.

Comment: Could you provide a working example with your HTML and CSS (using code snippets) in your post? We can help you much quicker if you do.

Comment: ul li span { display: inline-block; margin: 0 15px 0 15px; }